# In Grails template namespace how do you use a template that is in another directory

Tags: grails, templates, namespaces

Say I have a template called /sample/_mytemplate.gsp.

If I want to call this template from the same directory I can use

However, what if I am in another directory.  Then what do I do?

Say I'm in the view /sample2/mypage.gsp how do I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<g:render template="/sample/mytemplate" />
```

should do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wasn't clear enough in my question.  I wanted to know if there was a way to do it with the tmpl syntax.

Similar to
<tmpl:mytemplate ...>

Except that I don't know what syntax to use for the directory.

Comment: Grails does not currently have a syntax to use the <tmpl:template ...> namespace, you have to use render instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Grails 1.3.7 the following syntax

```
<tmpl:/sample/mytemplate />
```

works.